# Using maqetta as frontend for php app

Tags: php, html, rich-internet-application, maqetta

I recently found [maqetta](http://maqetta.org) which allows to creat rich html5 ui for webapps. I am not able to find the best way to integrate php app with this. Something like codeigniter.

Will placing php in the source be a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Maqetta... In Preview 6 of Maqetta, we began offering limited PHP support. From the release notes:

> Preview 6 includes limited support for *.php files. If you double-click on a *.php file in the Files palette, the HTML visual page editor opens. The visual editor ignores any  constructs in the *.php file (treating them the same as HTML comments). If you click on preview-in-browser for a *.php file, then the file is downloaded to the browser with mime-type text/html, which results in the browser doing whatever it does if cases when a *.html file happens to contain  constructs (usually ignored).
>
> This feature can be useful for web application developers where they need to include small amounts of PHP in their files, but note that Maqetta has no ability to actually run a PHP engine against the PHP constructs; all that Maqetta does is do its best to ignore everything within a  block.
>
> Developers who attempt to use this feature need to be careful that their *.php file (assuming  constructs are ignored) can be interpreted by the Maqetta page parser as a well-formed HTML file.

You might also be interested in the [Maqetta Users](http://ibm.co/Pudj7l) forum on Google Groups. There have been several PHP-related discussions, and it is regularly monitored by members of the Maqetta development team.

Tony Erwin
Maqetta Team
Blog: [Maqetta - Visual Authoring of HTML5 User Interfaces](http://ibm.co/Pudj7l)